# Asp.Net MVC - using RedirectToAction() to go to another controller in a different folder - 2 deep

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect from my SignInController to another controller in a different folder using:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminFunctions/Admin/Admin");
```

Can't seem to get it to work.

[image]

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

Here's the AdminController:

```
namespace GbngWebClient.Controllers.AdminFunctions.Admin
{
  public class AdminController : Controller
  {       
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }  
   }
}
```

Here's the error I get if I just use:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
```

[image]

Note: in my original folder stucture - under the Controllers folder. I used this and it worked fine.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
```

I then decided to organize the controllers and create the 2 deep folder structure and move the AdminController into it from where it was originally under the Controllers folder. I now get the error as indicated above.

Comment: use just ``return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin")``, the ``conrollerName`` is ``Admin``

Comment: That's what I had originally. See the error message added above.

Comment: Read this post on how to deal with subfolders, you probably haven't updated your routing settings so providing nesting folders will not work by default - https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-mvc-controller-subfolder-routing-url-request-response-attribute-routes/  and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/  also you could look into using areas  https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/area-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: Alejandro, I did the suggestion of attribute routing per ryadel.com. I added     [Route("AdminFunctions/Admin/Admin/{action}")] to the top of my Admin Controller and routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); to my RoguteConfig.  But I get the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation, There is a process call [View Discovery](https://asp.mvc-tutorial.com/views/view-discovery-connecting-controller-view/) that search the **Views** automatically or by specifying the path :

To do this, I think, you have two solutions:

1 - Create **Admin** folder under the **Views**, and not under **Views/AdminFunctions**. by using the below redirection :

1.1 - **HomeController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
}
```

1.2 - **AdminController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

2 - Keep the same hierarchy, and specify the path to locate `Index` view for *AdminController* :

2.1 - **HomeController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
}
```

2.2 - **AdminController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("/Views/AdminFunctions/Admin/Index.cshtml");
}
```

I hope this will help you fix the issue

Comment: Thanks. I used option 2.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
```

Home is my controller name and index is my view